# How to map through a rest parameter?

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to map through a rest parameter.

MDN says: *The rest parameter syntax allows us to represent an indefinite number of arguments as an array.*

So if `...numbers` is an array, when I use map on it ie `numbers.map()`, the array it's mapping is `[33,44,55]`. How can I now map each element of the `...numbers` array? I can't enter `numbers.map(numbers.slice(numbers.length - 1))` because each `numbers` is the total array.

TLDR; I guess to put it simply, how can I map each element of the rest parameter?

I'm out of ideas.

```
function checkLastDigit(num1, num2, num3) {
    function collectDigits(...numbers) {
        let digitsArr = [];
        digitsArr = numbers.map(collectLastDigit());
        return digitsArr;
    }

    function collectLastDigit() {
        return this.slice(this.length - 1)
    }

    return collectDigits(num1, num2, num3);
}
checkLastDigit(33, 44, 55);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just an array, so you can iterate through it just the way you would iterate through any array.

A couple problems with your current code: don't *invoke* the callback function while paassing it to `.map`, instead just *pass* the function:

```
digitsArr = numbers.map(collectLastDigit);
```

Also, numbers do not have a `slice` method , so `this.slice` won't work - if you want to `slice`, coerce to a string first. You may also use `slice(-1)` rather than passing the `length - 1`. Also,  `this` won't refer to the item being iterated over - instead, use the first parameter of the callback instead:

```js
function checkLastDigit(num1, num2, num3) {
    const collectLastDigit = num => String(num).slice(-1);
    const collectDigits = (...numbers) => numbers.map(collectLastDigit);

    return collectDigits(num1, num2, num3);
}
console.log(checkLastDigit(33, 44, 55));
```

If you want an array of numbers as a result rather than an array of strings, then change `collectLastDigit` to coerce back to a number:

```
const collectLastDigit = num => Number(String(num).slice(-1));
```

You could also use rest parameters in `checkLastDigit` too, if you wanted, rather than requiring exactly 3 arguments:

```js
function checkLastDigit(...nums) {
    const collectLastDigit = num => String(num).slice(-1);
    const collectDigits = (...numbers) => numbers.map(collectLastDigit);

    return collectDigits.apply(undefined, nums);
}
console.log(checkLastDigit(33, 44, 55));
```